# Bold text using RegExp Regular Expressions

Tags: excel, regex, vba, bold

I am trying to use regEx to find dates and bold them within text in multiple cells in a range but it appears that I am not using the correct expression for bolding text using regEx. The code below is working other than the bolding function. I need regEx as I need to bold all dates in the format of yyyy-mm-dd. I know that the regEx expression below is not correct to do this but i was going to get the bolding function working before i tackled the next part.

I have checked all the other questions and they all steer away from using regEx for bolding.

```
Sub Bold_a_date2()

Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim item As Variant
Dim arr As Variant
arr = Worksheets("Formatted").Range("M1:M1000")

Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
regEx.Pattern = "202[0-9]"

Dim text As Variant
Dim mc As MatchCollection, row As Long
row = 1

  For Each text In arr
    
    If regEx.test(text) = True Then
    Set mc = regEx.Execute(text)
    
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
    Debug.Print text
        
    End If
    
row = row + 1

Next text


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: RegEx finds text. The text is in a cell. The cell has a `Font` property which has a `Bold` property. So, what's in your variable `mc`? If the cell address can be extracted from that collection you could use code like `MyCell.Font.Bold = True` to change the font weight. As thing stand, there is no reason to believe that `mc` directly holds a range object because what you assigned to it is text.

Comment: Are the dates in cells by themselves, or contained in other text?  Do you want to bold the whole cell text, or just the date part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is a date value, the results will be weird. If the data is in text format, you can do as follows.

```
Sub Bold_a_date2()

Dim ws As Worksheets
Dim item As Variant
Dim arr As Range
Dim text As Range

Set arr = Worksheets("Formatted").Range("M1:M1000")
'Set arr = Worksheets("Formatted").Range("i1:i1000")

Dim regEx As New RegExp
regEx.Global = True
regEx.Pattern = "202[0-9]"


Dim mc As MatchCollection, row As Long
Dim m As Match
Dim s As Integer, l As Integer
    For Each text In arr
    
        If regEx.test(text) = True Then
            Set mc = regEx.Execute(text)
            For Each m In mc
                s = m.FirstIndex
                l = m.Length
                text.Characters(s + 1, l).Font.Bold = True
            Next m
            Debug.Print text
        End If
    Next text
End Sub
```

### String vs Datevalue

[image]

### multi case

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much, the date is stored as Text so this works really well

Comment: The only question i have is, how would you change this to pick up multiple dates in a cell?

Comment: at the moment it is only picking up the first instance of the pattern in each cell and bolding it and then it is moving to the next cell without bolding all instances of the pattern in the previous cell.

Comment: @SamOram, i added the other picture.  In my case it works fine. It would be nice to know your specific data.

Comment: Do you think it is the gaps that are stopping it going through each. It looks something like this. I had to take out the personal information. See up at original post

Comment: @SamOram, I haven't figured out exactly what your data type is. Is it a formula or something else? In case you don't know, try adding this to your code. `regEx.MultiLine = True`

Comment: @SamOram,Your regular pattern is 202[0-9], so 2019 is not included. The regular pattern is the problem.